# javascript manipulating html elements in a php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops

Consider the following:

```
<? php foreach($queryResult as $res) : ?>
    // output all table columns
    <form onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(); " method="post">
    <button id="b">edit</button>
    </form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Obviously, when the javascript function is called, the id of the buttons are the same, so:

```
document.getElementById(b).value;
```

won't work as expected. Is it possible to:

- Give each button a unique id attribute while it is created in the loop?
- Say I click the third button, is it possible for the javascript function to use that button that is clicked?

I absolutely have know idea how it can happen, looks like there's no way around it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, use the key with the `id`, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php, assuming this isn't an associative array. `foreach($queryResult as $key => $res)` and `id="b<?php echo $key;?>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give to each button a different id you can do this way:

```
<?php 
$i = 1; 
foreach($queryResult as $res) {  ?>
    // output all table columns
    <form onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(); " method="post">
    <button id="element-<?= $i ?>">edit</button>
    </form>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

For the second question: if you want to pass the id of the button to `javascriptFunction` you can modify your code this way:

```
return javascriptFunction(<?= '\'element-'. $i . "'" ?>);
```

and when `javascriptFunction` will be called, it will be passed the id of the button as the parameter and you could use it inside the function

Comment: when I try onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(<?= 'element-'$i ?>); ", it gave me an error saying undefined $i, expected "," or ";"

Comment: I just changed it to onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(<?= 'element'+$i ?>); " it's working now.

Comment: yes, there was an error: my purpose was to pass the string 'element-n' to the function. I have updated the code, now it should work

Comment: ok, but why does this work? onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(<?= 'element'+$i ?>); "

Comment: probably because it's evalutated in javascript, but not sure what it will produce...you could check in the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forach` and then you dont' have to keep track of the id iterator

```
foreach($queryResult as $id=>$res) {  ?>
    // output all table columns
    <form onsubmit="return javascriptFunction(); " method="post">
    <button id="element-<?php echo $id ?>">edit</button>
    </form>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Also, FWIW, its of course terrible practice to have multiple elements with the same id, but `document.querySelectorAll('#someID');` will give you multiple elements in most browsers.